# Placement of chart point /marker c#

Tags: c#

I am trying to use C# to replace charting on Microsoft Excel.

At the current moment, I have been able to plot a chart but there is some problem with the placement of the chart markers on the chart.

I had tried looking for chart markers but there is no much help so I decided to ask.

```
this.chart1.Series["X-T/B"].MarkerStyle = MarkerStyle.Diamond;
this.chart1.Series["X-T/B"].MarkerSize = 10;
this.chart1.Series["X-T/B"].MarkerColor = Color.Blue;

chart2.Series["Range"].MarkerStyle = MarkerStyle.Diamond;
chart2.Series["Range"].MarkerSize = 10;
chart2.Series["Range"].MarkerColor = Color.Blue;
```

The expected resulted will be the chart marker to be in the middle of the plot lines.

[Expected chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B9j0X.png)

[What I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NH6o9.png)

Comment: Are you using any libraries to modify the excel files? It would be beneficial to include that.

Comment: The markers will always sit __on the DataPoints__, not in-between. There is no offset.  Not sure how your code relates to the images, why you have two charts and which series is which..

Comment: there is no way that i can make it sit in between?